# How can I (programmatically) tell if an overlay is loaded?

Tags: winapi, overlay, shell-extensions

I writing a Windows program that uses overlays (to show certain states of files). The problem is that they sometimes don't appear (without reboot), although my logs say that the IsMemberOf function executed successfully. I'm not sure if I can force overlay display, but if I can't I would like to at least display a message saying that the icons don't work until reboot.

It there anyway to programmatically tell if icon overlays are not loaded for a particular file/folder?

All my google searches have returned nothing relevant.

Comment: i'm not sure if it's still relevant, but it relates to caching.
when isMemberOf returns "OK", it caches that entry. what is the exact scenario that it's not loaded? are you changing anything in your code? restart explorer.exe is enough.

if you can share your code i can help better